# How to do this query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this mysql table:

```
id       - auto_increment
id_stock - int
price    - double
date     - date
```

sample data is:

```
1   1   10.5   2010-08-10
2   1   16.5   2010-08-11
3   2   12.5   2010-08-12
```

now, i have to group by **id_stock** and search for the MAX(date) of the stock, then i have to compare the MAX(date) to a date i have to pass.

How to do it?

Thank you really much

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM Table
 GROUP BY Id_Stock
 HAVING Max(Date) = YourPassedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this using 'group' and 'having' together:

> select id, MAX(date) as max_date from
>   test group by id_stock having max_date > '2010-08-11'